# MySQL INSERT IGNORE Adding 1 to Non-Indexed column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a small report in a PHP while loop.
The query I'm running inside the while() loop is this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `tbl_reporting` SET datesubmitted = '2015-05-26', submissiontype = 'email', outcome = 0, totalcount = totalcount+1
```

I'm expecting the `totalcount` column to increment every time the query is run.
But the number stays at 1.
The UNIQUE index composes the first 3 columns.

Here's the Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_reporting` (
 `datesubmitted` date NOT NULL,
 `submissiontype` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `outcome` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `totalcount` mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 UNIQUE KEY `datesubmitted` (`datesubmitted`,`submissiontype`,`outcome`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

When I modify the query into a regular `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE `tbl_reporting` SET totalcount = totalcount+1 WHERE datesubmitted = '2015-05-26' AND submissiontype = 'email' AND outcome = 1
```

...it works.

Does `INSERT IGNORE` not allow adding numbers?  Or is my original query malformed?

I'd like to use the INSERT IGNORE, otherwise I'll have to query for the original record first, then insert, then eventually update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of what you're doing:

```
INSERT .... totalcount=totalcount+1
```

To calculate `totalcount+1`, the DB has to retrieve the current value of `totalcount`... which doesn't exist yet, because you're **CREATING** a new record, and there is **NO** existing data to retrieve the "old" value from.

e.g. you're trying eat your cake before you ever went to the store to buy the ingredients, let alone mix/bake them.

Comment: That is true! I did start creating the record first, for any eventual updates.

Comment: then don't use `insert ignore`. that tries to create a new record and aborts if it can't. if you want to update an existing record, then use `insert ... on duplicate key` instead.